# Why are my MVC controllers showing 404?

Tags: php, codeigniter, mamp

I've got an MVC project I'm trying to set up on a new computer. I'm using MAMP and codeigniter. For some reason I get a 404 error when I try to go to any controller.

But the weird thing is that the default controller, defined in the routes file seems to work ok.

Here's an example controller:

```
class Test_controller extends CI_Controller {
    public function index(){
       echo 'hello';
    }
}
```

When I go to `localhost:8888/test_controller` I get 404.

However, adding the following line to my `routes.php`...

```
$route['default_controller']="test_controller";
```

...and then navigating to `localhost:8888` seems to load the controller ok.

Comment: your controller's first letter must be capital i.e `Test_controller`

Comment: You're right. I've changed that now. But I'm still getting 404.

Comment: Try localhost:8888/index.php/test_controller

Comment: after localhost you have to give your project name and then controller name and if it is default one then give project name only....Is your project name test_controller...??

Comment: @killstreet That seems to work. I don't understand why though?

Comment: You do not have a .htaccess :)

Comment: @Abbas. Sorry- I forgot to say that I've set MAMP document root to point to this project.

Comment: I posted an awnser, have a look if that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the `.htaccess`, by default CI will need `/index.php/`controller to work, to remove the `index.php` you can use the HTaccess provided by Codeigniter or this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Place this outside the application folder with the name  ".htaccess"

Comment: Brilliant. This was the answer! Thank you.

Comment: I had copied my project from another machine, but it seems that .htaccess didn't copy, presumably because it is a hidden file.

Answer (score 0):

On Codeigniter CI3 which is case sensitive.

Make sure the file name has first letter upper case

```
Test_controller.php
```

And then controller class

```
<?php

class Test_controller extends CI_Controller {

   public function index() {
      echo 'hello';
   }

}
```

How to use Controllers [Link](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html)

Codeigniter Doc's [Link](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/)

Also make sure your base_url is set

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project/';
```

Comment: I'm setting the base_url ok I think: `$config['base_url']='';`

Comment: You do not need base_url set, it's just a quick access to the URL of the website. Still recommended to fill it in, but not neccecary.